# WebWorkers - Worker is not defined when calling new Worker()

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web-worker, comlink

I'm using next with typescript and trying to load a webworker.

For some reason - when I'm trying to initialize the webworker when I'm creating a hook - next tells me that Worker is not defined.

I'm using comlink but I suspect it's an issue with Next since comlink isn't in the mix at the point of error.

You can find the problematic line in below code snippet `useWorker.hooks.ts` in the function `makeWorkerApiAndCleanup`

Does anyone understand why this is happening?

`const worker = new Worker(url);`

useWorker.hooks.ts

```
import { wrap, releaseProxy } from "comlink";
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";

function makeWorkerApiAndCleanup() {
  const url = new URL("./useWorker.worker", import.meta.url)
  const worker = new Worker(url);
  const workerApi = wrap<import("./useWorker.worker").WorkerType>(worker);

  const cleanup = () => {
    workerApi[releaseProxy]();
    worker.terminate();
  };

  const workerApiAndCleanup = { workerApi, cleanup };

  return workerApiAndCleanup;
}

function useWorker() {
  const workerApiAndCleanup = useMemo(() => makeWorkerApiAndCleanup(), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { cleanup } = workerApiAndCleanup;
    return () => {
      cleanup();
    };
  }, [workerApiAndCleanup]);

  return workerApiAndCleanup;
}

function useImplementation() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const { workerApi } = useWorker();

  useEffect(() => {
    workerApi.workerFunction();
    setData({});
  }, [workerApi]);

  return data;
}

export default useImplementation;
```

useWorker.worker.ts

```
import { expose } from 'comlink';
import { workerFunction } from './functions';

const worker = {
  workerFunction,
};

export type WorkerType = typeof worker;

expose(worker);
```

useWorker/index.ts

```
import useWorker from './useWorker.hooks';

export { useWorker };
```

Comment: did you solve this?